# Получение переменных скрипта | JSoup | Kotlin

Tags: регулярные-выражения, парсер, kotlin, jsoup

Я получил после парса текст:

```
var User = new CUser({id: 0, login: 'anonymous'});

var Book = new CBook({
    id: 14470,
    owner_id: 129537,
    facecontrol: 1,
    s_lang: 2,
    t_lang: 1,
    n_verses: 150,
    n_vars: 150,
    d_vars: 150,
    typ: 'A',
    s_title: 'Title',
    t_title: 'Название',
});
```

Как мне его распарсить так, чтобы получить s_title, t_title или т.п.? Видел варианты с regex, но ничего не получилось.

```
for(script in scripts){
                if (script.data().contains("s_title")){
                    val p: Pattern = Pattern.compile("(?is)t_title=\"(.+?)\"") // Regex for the value of the key
                    val m: Matcher = p.matcher(script.html())
                    while( m.find() )
                    {
                        Log.i("ParserShell", "${m.group()} = ${m.group(1)}")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/CBook\(\{.*s_title: '(.+?)'.*\}\)/
```

Вместо s_title укажите то, что вам нужно получить

[image: Проверил, вроде работает.]